# How configure get method in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Could someone help me with me issue.
I have a get method to API example:
https://example.com/api/v5/otp?template_id=application/json&mobile=123456789&authkey=*Authkey*

Modbile and authkey its headers in http request, which filling manually.

I want to monitoring "status" of api, with this request. But I dont know how I can do it with promethues/grafana.

Could you please assist with it. Thank you for help.

Comment: You question is not clear, Are you the author of the API service? Do you want to instrument the API service itself to track the status of any traffic or do you want to to run the web request against example.com every 60 seconds from a client and log the result?